# Get a single value from JSON looping on a click event [jQuery/JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, click

First of all, sorry for my english.

Hello everyone,

I am trying to create a small application which is actually a ranking. I'm recovering data from a JSON file.

The application is divided into two parts: a left column that includes all participants with their names and their pictures and a right column that displays their characteristics.

I want to display the exact same value in the right column when I click on a picture.

- I made a JSON file
- I used the $.getJSON to recover my datas
- I made a each loop and display all the datas on the left side (it works)
- I added a class "active" when i click on a picture

Here is my JSON example file :

```
{
  "data": {
    "personalities": [
      {
        "position": 1,
        "name": "Jeff Bezos",
        "country": "America",
        "gender": "men",
        "photo": "rank1.jpg",
        "description": "Donec sit amet elit a nulla sagittis sollicitudin eu nec eros. Nam finibus, leo bibendum interdum dictum, velit turpis faucibus purus, quis blandit lectus tortor sed felis. Suspendisse viverra massa a condimentum pharetra. Proin convallis sit amet mi vitae tincidunt. Duis vitae pretium orci, et mattis metus.",      },
      {
        "position": 2,
        "name": "Bill Gates",
        "country": "American",
        "gender": "men",
        "photo": "rank2.jpg",
        "description": "Donec sit amet elit a nulla sagittis sollicitudin eu nec eros. Nam finibus, leo bibendum interdum dictum, velit turpis faucibus purus, quis blandit lectus tortor sed felis. Suspendisse viverra massa a condimentum pharetra. Proin convallis sit amet mi vitae tincidunt. Duis vitae pretium orci, et mattis metus."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is my loop which display all the information on the left side (which is working) :

```
$.each(result.data.personalities, function(index, element) {
        const box = document.createElement("div");
        boxPersonalities.className = "box_personalities";
        columnLeft.append(box);

        const picture = document.createElement("img");
        picture.className = "box_personalities-picture";
        picture.src = path + element.photo;
        boxPersonalities.append(picture);

        const containerTitle = document.createElement("div");
        containerTitle.className = "box_personalities_container-title";
        boxPersonalities.append(containerTitle);

        const position = document.createElement("h1");
        position.className = "box_personalities_container-title-position";
        position.innerHTML = element.position + "&#160";
        containerTitle.append(position);

        const name = document.createElement("h1");
        name.className = "box_personalities_container-title-name";
        name.innerHTML = element.name;
        containerTitle.append(name);
```

I tried something like this but it didn't work. I want to display the exact same value in the right column when I click on a picture. On the right side, i will add more informations like gender, country, description, etc.

The console.log(index) gives me the associate number to the left picture. The following code is inside the each loop.

```
$(".box_personalities").each(function(index) {
          $(this).click(function() {
            console.log(element.name);
          });
        });
// Want to display the EXACT SAME value on the right than picture clicked on the left
```

Tell me if you have questions,
Many thanks for your help

Comment: You can do like the below:
<code>
<div class="anyclass" data-element='{"id":'1',"name":'abc'}'></div>
<div class="anyclass" data-element='{"id":'2',"name":'abcd'}'></div>
<div class="anyclass" data-element='{"id":'3',"name":'abcde'}'></div>
<div class="anyclass" data-element='{"id":'4',"name":'abcdef'}'></div>
$('.anyclass').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).data('element'));
});
</code>
When your div is made on dom then on click of any div you can get the data.

Comment: Hello Vivek,
Thanks for your comment. I will take a loot.

Maybe Can you format the code please ? thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like the below:

```
<div class="anyclass" data-element='{"id":'1',"name":'abc'}'></div>
<div class="anyclass" data-element='{"id":'2',"name":'abcd'}'></div>
<div class="anyclass" data-element='{"id":'3',"name":'abcde'}'></div>
<div class="anyclass" data-element='{"id":'4',"name":'abcdef'}'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.anyclass').click(function() {
 console.log($(this).data('element'));
});
</script>
```

When your div is made on dom then on click of any div you can get the data.

Comment: ok i understand, i have to add a data-attribute on my div and recover data from the data-attribute, right ?

Comment: Yup you are right..... Please upvote you get any help from my code thanks.